# Parsing YAML-like text file into hash structure

Tags: regex, perl

I've got the text file:

```
country = { 
    tag = ENG 
    ai = { 
        flags = { } 
        combat = { ROY WLS PUR SCO EIR FRA DEL USA QUE BGL MAH MOG VIJ MYS DLH GUJ ORI JAI ASS MLC MYA ARK PEG TAU HYD } 
        continent = { "Oceania" } 
        area = { "America" "Maine" "Georgia" "Newfoundland" "Cuba" "Bengal" "Carnatic" "Ceylon" "Tanganyika" "The Mascarenes" "The Cape" "Gold" "St Helena" "Guiana" "Falklands" "Bermuda" "Oregon" } 
        region = { "North America" "Carribean" "India" } 
        war = 50 
        ferocity = no 
    }
    date = { year = 0 month = january day = 0 } 
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to parse this text into perl hash structure, so that the output after data dump looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'country' => {
                         'ai' => {
                                   'area' => [
                                               'America',
                                               'Maine',
                                               'Georgia',
                                               'Newfoundland',
                                               'Cuba',
                                               'Bengal',
                                               'Carnatic',
                                               'Ceylon',
                                               'Tanganyika',
                                               'The Mascarenes',
                                               'The Cape',
                                               'Gold',
                                               'St Helena',
                                               'Guiana',
                                               'Falklands',
                                               'Bermuda',
                                               'Oregon'
                                             ],
                                   'combat' => [
                                                 'ROY',
                                                 'WLS',
                                                 'PUR',
                                                 'SCO',
                                                 'EIR',
                                                 'FRA',
                                                 'DEL',
                                                 'USA',
                                                 'QUE',
                                                 'BGL',
                                                 'MAH',
                                                 'MOG',
                                                 'VIJ',
                                                 'MYS',
                                                 'DLH',
                                                 'GUJ',
                                                 'ORI',
                                                 'JAI',
                                                 'ASS',
                                                 'MLC',
                                                 'MYA',
                                                 'ARK',
                                                 'PEG',
                                                 'TAU',
                                                 'HYD'
                                               ],
                                   'continent' => [
                                                    'Oceania'
                                                  ],
                                   'ferocity' => 'no',
                                   'flags' => [],
                                   'region' => [
                                                 'North America',
                                                 'Carribean',
                                                 'India'
                                               ],
                                   'war' => 50
                                 },
                         'date' => {
                                     'day' => 0,
                                     'month' => 'january',
                                     'year' => 0
                                   },
                         'tag' => 'ENG'
                       }
        };
```

Hardcoded version might look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
use warnings;
use strict;

my $ret;

$ret->{'country'}->{tag} = 'ENG';
$ret->{'country'}->{ai}->{flags} = [];
my @qw = qw( ROY WLS PUR SCO EIR FRA DEL USA QUE BGL MAH MOG VIJ MYS DLH GUJ ORI JAI ASS MLC MYA ARK PEG TAU HYD );
$ret->{'country'}->{ai}->{combat} = \@qw; 
$ret->{'country'}->{ai}->{continent} =  ["Oceania"];
$ret->{'country'}->{ai}->{area} =  ["America", "Maine", "Georgia", "Newfoundland", "Cuba", "Bengal", "Carnatic", "Ceylon", "Tanganyika", "The Mascarenes", "The Cape", "Gold", "St Helena", "Guiana", "Falklands", "Bermuda", "Oregon"];
$ret->{'country'}->{ai}->{region} = ["North America", "Carribean", "India"];
$ret->{'country'}->{ai}->{war} = 50;
$ret->{'country'}->{ai}->{ferocity} = 'no';
$ret->{'country'}->{date}->{year} = 0;
$ret->{'country'}->{date}->{month} = 'january';
$ret->{'country'}->{date}->{day} = 0;

sub hash_sort {
  my ($hash) = @_;
  return [ (sort keys %$hash) ];
}

$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = \hash_sort;

print Dumper($ret);
```

I have to admit I have a huge problem dealing with nested curly brackets.
I've tried to solve it by using greedy and ungreedy matching, but it seems it didn't do the trick. I've also read about extended patterns (like (?PARNO)) but I have absolutely no clue how to use them in my particular problem. Order of data is irrelevant, since I have the hash_sort subroutine.
I'll apprieciate any help.

Comment: What created the text file. My solution would be to find a way to create the text file so that it really was a YAML file. It's crazy to do otherwise! It's easier to create it in a standard format, and it's easier to read it!

Comment: Europa Universalis to be precise ;). But still, it's not about game hacking, it's about doing collage project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I broke it down to some simple assumptions:

1. An entry would consist of an identifier followed by an equals sign
2. An entry would be one of three basic types: a level or set or a single value
3. A set has 3 forms: 1) quoted, space-separated list; 2) key-value pairs, 3) qw-like unquoted list
4. A set of key-value pairs must contain an indentifier for a key and either nonspaces or a quoted
   value for a value

See the interspersed comments.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $simple_value_RE
    = qr/^ \s* (\p{Alpha}\w*) \s* = \s* ( [^\s{}]+ | "[^"]*" ) \s* $/x
    ;
my $set_or_level_RE
    = qr/^ \s* (\w+) \s* = \s* [{] (?: ([^}]+) [}] )? \s* $/x
    ;
my $quoted_set_RE
    = qr/^ \s* (?: "[^"]+" \s+ )* "[^"]+" \s* $/x
    ;
my $associative_RE
    = qr/^ \s* 
        (?: \p{Alpha}\w* \s* = \s* (?: "[^"]+" | \S+ ) \s+ )*
        \p{Alpha}\w* \s* = \s* (?: "[^"]+" | \S+ ) 
        \s* $
    /x
    ;
my $pair_RE = qr/ \b ( \p{Alpha}\w* ) \s* = \s* ( "[^"]+" | \S+ )/x;

sub get_level { 
    my $handle = shift;
    my %level;
    while ( <$handle> ) {
        # if the first character on the line is a close, then we're done
        # at this level
        last if  m/^\s*[}]/; 
        my ( $key, $value );

        # get simple values
        if (( $key, $value ) =  m/$simple_value_RE/ ) { 
            # done.
        }
        elsif (( $key, my $complete_set ) = m/$set_or_level_RE/ ) {
            if ( $complete_set ) {
                if ( $complete_set =~ m/$quoted_set_RE/ ) { 
                    # Pull all quoted values with global flag
                    $value = [ $complete_set =~ m/"([^"]+)"/g ];
                }
                elsif ( $complete_set =~ m/$associative_RE/ ) { 
                    # going to create a hashref. First, with a global flag
                    # repeatedly pull all qualified pairs
                    # then split them to key and value by spliting them at
                    # the first '='
                    $value 
                        = { map { split /\s*=\s*/, $_, 2 } 
                                ( $complete_set =~ m/$pair_RE/g )
                        };
                }
                else {
                    # qw-like
                    $value = [ split( ' ', $complete_set ) ];
                }
            }
            else { 
                $value = get_level( $handle );
            }
        }
        $level{ $key } = $value;
    }
    return wantarray ? %level : \%level;
}

my %base = get_level( \*DATA );
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, as David suggested, the easiest way would be to get whatever produced the file to use a standard format.  JSON, YAML, or XML would be much easier to parse.

But if you really have to parse this format, I'd write a grammar for it using [Regexp::Grammars](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp%3a%3aGrammars) (if you can require Perl 5.10) or [Parse::RecDescent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parse%3a%3aRecDescent) (if you can't).  This'll be a little tricky, especially because you seem to be using braces for both hashes & arrays, but it should be doable.

Answer (score 2):

The contents look pretty regular.  Why not perform some substitutions on the content and convert it to hash syntax, then eval it.  That would be a quick and dirty way to convert it.

You can also write a parser, assuming you know the grammar.

Comment: I can't do that. It's true that this would be quick, but unfortunately I also need it to be clean. Thanks anyway